# command "ionic cordova emulate android" does not work

Tags: android, ionic-framework, gradle, proxy, emulation

I have problem running my project to android emulator: When I run this command "ionic cordova emulate android", it goes to errors.
I am running putty with dynamic ssh and socks tunnel.
Complete log of my terminal is shown below.

```
PS D:\Hamid\wooionic2> ionic cordova run android
...
[12:06:30]  sass started ...
Without `from` option PostCSS could generate wrong source map and will not find Browserslist config. Set it to CSS file path or to `undefined`
to prevent this warning.
```

...

> cordova run android
>       Android Studio project detected

```
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Hamid\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_172
studio
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom'.
               > dl.google.com:443 failed to respond
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom'.
               > jcenter.bintray.com:443 failed to respond
      >
Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom'.
               > maven.google.com:443 failed to respond

   * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
(node:7272) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


BUILD FAILED in 1s
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (D:\Hamid\wooionic2\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
(node:7272) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:7272) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

[OK] Your app has been deployed.
     Did you know you can live-reload changes from your app with --livereload?
```

It says:

```
Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom'.
               > dl.google.com:443 failed to respond
```

Where is the bug?

Answer (score 0):

I disabled the putty (that acts as a proxy) and run my command again: "cordova emulate android"

but it felts to new errors this time:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
```

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
>        Required by:
>            project :
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom'.
>   Connect to **127.0.0.1:8085** [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect

The 127.0.0.1:8085 is the address and port that I set to puty ssh tunnels.
But I could not find where is the setting to remove this proxy from my project. 
Finally and fortunately I found it in this file (gradle.properties):

C:\Users\USERNAME.gradle\gradle.properties

In this file I removed this lines:

```
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8085
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8085
```

and the **problem goes away**. But I don't know yet how gradle gets and sets this proxy settings! anyone know it?